# Enabling a button on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

So I have for example 2 pages (jquery mobile) so the different pages are actually divs in the same html. So what I have is a page 3 which loads images from a database, and when you click on an image it goes to page #two and drops the image in a div on that page #two. Now I have a button that is disabled="disabled". And when the function is called to place the image into that page #two div it redirects automatically to page #two. Now the button is disabled by itself. So I tried to add this to the function of adding images: document.getElementById("resetbutton").disabled = false;

What happens is when the page is redirected back again to page #two the button reloads so overwrites the disabled false, since it is automatically disabled. What are the solutions for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which event are you binding to when you call document.getElementById("resetbutton").disabled = false;
Could you post some sample code?

Comment: <button id="chooseobject" onclick="location.href='#popup';">Kies Object</button>
<button id="resetobject" disabled="disabled" onclick="resetobject()">Reset</button>

When clicking on an image opslaan() function is called.

Comment: function opslaan(hetPad)

{
$('div#content2').append('<div id="poep" class="ui-widget-content ui-resizable ui-draggable"><img src="'+hetPad+'"><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1001; "></div></div>');
window.location = '#two';
window.getElementById("resetbutton").disabled = false;
}

<script>

Comment: why are you calling window.location = '#two'; ?
Can't you use jqm's changePage()?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like:

```
$('#two').live('pageinit',function(event){
    if (resetButton) { // variable to determine active/disabled
        $('#resetbutton').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I would think that you could simply call ('#resetbutton').addClass('active'); (similar to what you are doing) in the function... are you dynamically generating that content on page 2? If so, you should be able to bind to the pageinit or pageshow event and determine the button state.